# Euclidean algorithm explanation?

Tags: java, algorithm, euclidean-algorithm

Two inputs, `number1 = 36` and `number2 = 27`, are passed to the following code for finding G.C.D of two numbers using Euclidean algorithm.

```
public static int euclideanAlgo(int number1, int number2){
    int temp;
    while(number2 != 0){
        temp = number2;
        number2 = number1 % number2;
        number1 = temp;
    }
    return number1;
}
```

During the first iteration, in line `number1 = temp` :

Is the value of `number1` = 27? or is it the updated value 9,since `temp = number2` and in the next line `number2 = number1 % number2` which becomes 9?

Comment: `number2 = number1 % number2` this assignment does not change the value of temp.

Comment: The _temp_ value will remain.  A subsequent change to _number2_ will not change _temp_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implying that since *number2* is updated, the previous assignment of *temp* would then change.

This is not the case with *Java*, although this technique is used widely in many other coding languages, such as *C*.
In fact, *Java* was designed specifically with an aim to avoid this programming concept.

It is referred to as referencing, and dereferencing.  Here is a great Wikipedia article on the technique.
*[Wikipedia – Reference_(computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science))*.

It was very useful in early coding languages, as CPU time was critical.
As computers advanced the concept was lost, and deemed unnecessary.

I believe in intense processing applications, this technique is still preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to think of `number1`, `number2`, and `temp` as three separate boxes, each containing a number. An assignment `a = b` is in fact `a ← b`, that is, it copies the value from box `b` into box `a`. It does **not** create any links between boxes.

Here are the values in boxes after each line:

```
...                            number1  number2  temp
...                               36       27     ??
temp = number2;                   36       27     27
number2 = number1 % number2;      36        9     27
number1 = temp;                   27        9     27
```

Answer (score 0):

You we follow execution of the algorithm we have :

```
number1 = 36
number2 = 27

number2 == 0? // No number2 = 27
    temp = number2 // temp=27
    number2 = number1%number2 // number2 = 36%27 = 9
    number1 = temp // number1=27

number2 == 0? // No number2 = 9
    temp = number2 // temp = 9
    number2 = number1%number2 // number2 = 27%9 = 0
    number1 = temp // number1 = 9

return number1 // number1 = 9
```